# Einbiegen oder abbiegen?

Tags: difference, word-choice

Sind beide folgende Varianten richtig?

> Biegen Sie in die erste Straße rechts ein.
>   Biegen Sie in die erste Straße rechts ab.

Wenn ja,  liegt ein Bedeutungsunterschied vor, und sind beide gleich häufig?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In meinem eigenen Sprachgebrauch sind die beiden Begriffe vollkommen gleichwertig (Genauso wie wenn ich aus einem Zimmer in ein andres gehe - Ich gehe rein und raus - Beides meint denselben Vorgang, und je nachdem, ob mir wichtiger ist, wo ich herkomme oder wo ich hingehe, verwende ich hinaus- oder hineingehen).

Die Straßenverkehrsordnung (die es eigentlich wissen müsste ;) ) spricht nur vom *Abbiegen*, allerdings auch vom *Einfahren* in eine Strasse, meint damit aber nur das Einfahren in einen öffentlichen Verkehrsraum beim z.B. Verlassen eines Privatgrundstücks. *Einbiegen* habe ich dort auf die Schnelle nicht gefunden.

Und Wikipedia ist der Ansicht, dass in der Verkehrsplanung die *Bedeutung* (Größe, Ordnung,...) der Straße eine Rolle spielte, ob man denn nun *ab-* oder *einbiegt* https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbiegen_%28Stra%C3%9Fenverkehr%29#Verkehrsplanung , bleibt uns aber weitere Referenzen dafür schuldig.

Comment: Tausend Dank für den fantastischen Verweis auf Wikipedia !

Answer (score 7):

Richtig ist die erste Variante, da man *in* eine Straße nur *einbiegen* kann.

- *Biegen* Sie in die erste Straße rechts *ein*.

*Abbiegen* kann zB in folgendem Satz verwendet werden:

- *Biegen* Sie an der nächsten Kreuzung rechts *ab*.

Comment: [Hier](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/in+die+stra%C3%9Fe+abbiegen.html)  sind mehr als 30 Beispiele in denen geschrieben ist, dass  man **in** eine Straße abbiegt. Hältst du sie alle für falsch?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Ich kann natürlich gerne hinzufügen, dass auch die zweite Variante benutzt wird - das ist mir auch bewusst. Ich bin allerdings der Meinung, dass es syntaktisch nicht korrekt ist.

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung, jera, aber warum ist es syntaktisch nicht korrekt ? Das ist mir als Ausländer nicht klar.

Comment: Der Satzteil _in die Straße_ suggeriert, dass die Bewegung _hinein_ passiert. Also _[hin]einbiegen in_ und nicht _abbiegen in_. _Abbiegen_ verwende ich mit _auf_ zB bei _auf den Ring abbiegen_ oder _auf den Graben abbiegen_ (Straße in der Wiener Altstadt).

Comment: Syntaktisch halte ich beide für akzeptabel. Ich sehe allerdings eine Abhängigkeit vom Bezugspunkt: Für jemanden, der sich in der genannten Straße befindet, liegt *einbiegen* deutlich näher.

Comment: @tofro, ah, ich bin in der Zeile verrutscht. Ich dachte, es sei "in eine andere Richtung biegen" vs "die bisherige Richtung ändern und in eine Seitenstraße, einen Seitenweg o. Ä. hineingehen, -fahren". Das "in eine andere Richtung biegen" bezieht sich allerdings nicht mehr auf das Abbiegen als Richtungsänderung. Ich lösch meinen vorherigen Kommentar