# "ab" and "nach" in "Biegen Sie nach rechts ab"

Tags: grammar

> An der großen Kreuzung biegen Sie dann nach rechts ab.

In this sentence, what does the *ab* mean? I don't think it is meant to split off.

Oh by the way, while we're at it, what is *nach* there for as well? I know *nach* can mean *turn*, but I thought *biegen* was there for that?

Comment: Siehe auch: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28612/einbiegen-oder-abbiegen which elaborates quite a bit on *abbiegen*. Might even be a duplicate

Comment: These are two unrelated questions. One is asking for a preposition, the other is about a separable verb. Besides, a basic German textbook should cover both questions.

Comment: Oh goddamnit. A close-worthy question in the HNQ!

Comment: Thanks Em1 for that. I'm not sure about the "put on hold' box though. After all, it is a grammar related question

Comment: @swaffi The [on hold] box means that your question is temporarily closed because we do not see it as a good fit for the site. Compare [help/on-topic]. Please read the notice behind the bullet point. If you feel that your question would still be a good fit for the site, you are invited to [edit] accordingly — in this case why a grammar book didn’t help you.

Answer (score 12):

"Ab" is a part of verb "[abbiegen](http://mobile-dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/Abbiegen)". It's a separable verb therefore "ab" is in the end of the sentence.

"Nach" never means "turn". It means (in this case) "to" (in other cases "nach" can mean f.e. "after"). Your confusion might be based on the expression like "nach links" which you understand as "turn to the left", but the correct translation would be just "to the left".

Comment: Yes Alex, you hit the nail on the head with that one. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The word *abbiegen* basically consists of two parts: The prefix *ab-* and the root *biegen*.
There are a lot of words in German with prefixes like that. For example:

- abhören (to tap)
- abarbeiten (to work off)
- abschießen (to shoot down)

In English you would say *"Shoot them down!"* or *"Work it off."*.
So you do in German: *"Schießt sie ab!"* or *"Arbeitet es ab."*.

But sometimes a verb loses this extra bit, but not very often.
*To remove* has no extra bit, but *to take off* has; thus being closer to one possible translation: *abnehmen*.

Comment: I agree with @CarstenS and, hence, removed the word syllable from that answer altogether.

Comment: Upvoted now, even though I am not sure if “work off” exists.