# Bedeutung von "rein" bei einer Richtungsangabe

Tags: meaning

Ich hab eine Frage nach der Richtung gestellt und jemand antwortet mit

> ... nach der Kreuzung gleich links rein.

Was bedeutet *rein* da?

Comment: Die Verwendung von rein (herein) ist hier außerdem falsch, weil "her" eine Bewegung  auf den Sprecher zu bedeutet. Es müsste "hinein" heißen, und in einigen Mundarten würde man tatsächlich "und dann links in die Straße 'nein" sagen.

Comment: Umgangssprachlich ist daran mE nichts auszusetzen. Obwohl in der Schriftsprache der Unterschied zwischen hinein und herein beachtet wird, ist das ugs. nicht immer so, und "rein" wird für beides verwendet. Auch Duden kennt "rein" mit den Bedeutungen "hinein" und "herein": http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/rein_hinein_herein

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das ist eine umgangssprachliche Verkürzung von

> nach der Kreuzung in die erste Straße links einbiegen.

Man biegt also in die Straße (hin-) ein. Siehe auch [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/28612/1696).

Es ist nützlich, sich zu merken, dass man sich *in* einer Straße aber *auf* einem Platz befindet.

Answer (score 3):

*rein* ist die umgangssprachliche Kurzform für *hinein*.

Siehe [Dudeneintrag](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/rein_hinein_herein)

Answer (score 0):

"*rein*" bedeutet hier "*(in die Straße) hinein*". Es ist eine Kurzform von "*herein*".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49290/discussion-on-answer-by-eller-eine-frage-nach-der-richtung).